# Powershell Open New Calendar Event

Tags: powershell, outlook, calendar

I would like to open outlook with a new event dialog, filled in with date, name...., from Powershell. Is this even possible? All the solutions I have found until create an event and require Outlook to be closed.

Answer (score -2):

```
[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application").ActiveWindow().Activate()
```